# Rails 3.2.0.rc1 assets not showing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application works locally, but the stylesheets are not working on Heroku. I'm having difficulty understanding why.

I'm using Heroku's Cedar stack.

One of my ideas, is that my assets are not precompiling successfully:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

```
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "*/": expected "}", was ""
  (in /path/to/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

Can anyone explain why precompile is complaining about the `*/` on the very last line of application.css? It's meant to be there. If anyone has a fix, that would be ideal as well.

**application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require reset
 *= require style
 *= require projects
 *= require_self
*/
```

**Update**
I attempted to add quotes in my application.css, and it doesn't make a difference. Something isn't setting right I guess. But I'm unable to precompile to send to heroku. When I load the site, there is rarely any formatting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, how come you're using Rails 3.1rc5? - that came out almost 6 months ago, can you not up it to 3.1.3 which is the latest release? You could be fighting bugs (and certainly Rails security fixes) which have since been fixed and certainly using updated dependent gems.

Your syntax is exactly right for the manifest files (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) - The problem may also lie in the files you are requiring, so the error may be being misreported. You could try a process of elimination by removing some or the require statements trying a precompile and seeing if it's successful or not, then readding them to find the troublesome file?

Comment: Oops, I apologize, I am using Rails 3.2.0.rc1, I don't know why I thought I was using the older version. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Also, when I do a precompile, how does that work? Does it precompile only required files from the application.css? Or does it precompile all assets regardless if they are used or not?

Comment: it will do all files that the manifest directs it to use and mashes it together into a single application.css file. If you view source on dev you should see all the individual files listed.

Comment: Right, okay, I do see all individual files on dev. Going to try your method and see what I can come up with. Thanks. So maybe it's having a problem with one of the required files instead of the manifest file itself, interesting thoughts.

Comment: Found it, there was a problem in one of the stylesheets that I had purchased, and I never noticed it! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you need to quote your files:

```
*= require 'reset'
*= require 'style'
*= require 'projects'
*= require_self
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, do you know why? It works in development without.

Comment: Dev won't be pre-compiling.  I think you need to quote because they're strings

Comment: I added the strings, but the command I'm using to precompile is still failing with the same error.